# Get email from LDAP using Ansible

Tags: active-directory, ansible, ldap

I have a list of first and last name and I need to check them against my LDAP and get the emails.
I have been working with the ldap_entry and ldap_attr, but those modules don't provide information.

This will ensure that the user exist and it will try to create it, but it doesn't provide information:

```
- name: Make sure we have an user
  ldap_entry:
    dn: CN=xxx,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
    objectClass: person
    server_uri: ldap://ldap.test.com
    bind_dn: CN=admin,OU=Functional Accounts,DC=example,DC=com
    bind_pw: xxxxxxxxx
```

Is there any way to get the email from a user using ansible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to retrieve that information using the [community.general.ldap_search](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ldap_search_module.html) Ansible module using the `attrs` parameter. You might need to change the name of the attribute from `mail` to match your LDAP server's email attribute name.

```yaml
- name: Retrieve a user's mail attribute.
  community.general.ldap_search:
    dn: CN=xxx,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
    attrs:
      - mail
    server_uri: ldap://ldap.test.com
    bind_dn: CN=admin,OU=Functional Accounts,DC=example,DC=com
    bind_pw: xxxxxxxxx
  register: ldap_search_result

- name: Print a user's mail attribute.
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: |
      DN: {{ ldap_search_result.results[0].dn }}
      mail: {{ ldap_search_result.results[0].mail }}
```

The `community.general.ldap_search` module requires the `python_ldap` package to be installed which in turn [requires some LDAP related packages](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html#build-prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

Its not an answer, but a workaround.
I end up installing ldapsearch and I use the command option on ansible.

```
- name: Test ldap
  command: ldapsearch -x -h ldap.test.com -D "admin" -w "xxxxxxx" -b "CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com" "cn={{item}}" -s sub "(cn=*)" mail
  register: ldap_output
  with_items: "{{owner_list}}"
```